# Error in syntax with raw_input

Tags: python

```
    version = "Alpha"
print " ------------------------------------"
print "|            BlackJack               |"
print " ------------------------------------"
print"   V: " + version + "         -by cookie"
print ""
from random import randint
CartaA1 = (randint(1,13))
CartaA2 = (randint(1,13))
Carta = (randint(1,13))
Carta2 = (randint(1,13))
print ""
print "Primera carta del adversario:", CartaA2
print ""
print ""
print ""
print "Su carta", Carta
Accion = raw_input("Desea agarrar otra carta o dejar así.(Agarrar/Esperar)")
if Accion = "Agarrar"
    print "Sus cartas son:", Carta, Carta2
```

I got the error on the `if Accion = "Agarrar`:

```
line 19
    if Accion = "Agarrar"
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Comparison operator is `==`, not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` operator is only used for assignment in Python. If you're doing a comparison (as you are in your `if` statement), you want `==` instead. You also need a colon at the end of the line (all Python statements that introduce blocks have colons):

```
if Accion == "Agarrar":
```